# ROS use libusb C++

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, ros, libusb

I'm trying to use a old C++ program of mine within ROS Lunar that uses the library libusb to get data from joysticks.

I've read on the internet that I should make `#include "libusb-1.0/libusb.h"` to use the library, but I've written `#include "libusb/libusb.h"` and I don't know why. I think I've never tested it with ROS and just left things in a unstable state.

Next here it is my CMakesLists.txt of my package:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(controllers)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
# )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES controllers
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
 include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
add_library(deviceManager src/deviceManager.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/controllers_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} deviceManager)

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_controllers.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

However it throws the following error:

```
CMakeFiles/controllers_node.dir/src/controllers_node.cpp.o: In function `main':
controllers_node.cpp:(.text+0x50e): undefined reference to `libusb_claim_interface'
controllers_node.cpp:(.text+0x62d): undefined reference to `libusb_bulk_transfer'
controllers_node.cpp:(.text+0x719): undefined reference to `libusb_release_interface'
/home/gpereira/Documents/pitank/devel/lib/libdeviceManager.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
/home/gpereira/Documents/pitank/devel/lib/libdeviceManager.so: undefined reference to `libusb_init'
/home/gpereira/Documents/pitank/devel/lib/libdeviceManager.so: undefined reference to `libusb_detach_kernel_driver'
/home/gpereira/Documents/pitank/devel/lib/libdeviceManager.so: undefined reference to `libusb_open'
/home/gpereira/Documents/pitank/devel/lib/libdeviceManager.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_list'
/home/gpereira/Documents/pitank/devel/lib/libdeviceManager.so: undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
/home/gpereira/Documents/pitank/devel/lib/libdeviceManager.so: undefined reference to `libusb_kernel_driver_active'
/home/gpereira/Documents/pitank/devel/lib/libdeviceManager.so: undefined reference to `libusb_free_device_list'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [controllers/CMakeFiles/controllers_node.dir/build.make:115: /home/gpereira/Documents/pitank/devel/lib/controllers/controllers_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:263: controllers/CMakeFiles/controllers_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

Comment: You use libusb library, but where do you **link** (`target_link_libraries`) with it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev How do I do that?

Comment: As I said above, with [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_link_libraries.html) command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Can you explain why?

Comment: Explain why **what**? Why is you question duplicate? You have the same error message. Or why do you need to the library?

Comment: @Tsyvarev No, I've read what you pointed out but I didn't get your point, can you give a detailed answer? I know Google also, don't need you to do it for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this! just added `usb-1.0` to the `target_link_libraries`.
All good!